# Использовать один и тот-же шаблон для трехмерного и одномерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблон, который принимает трехмерный массив для нахождения максимума. Суть задачи состоит в том, что этот шаблон должен  находить максимум и в одномерном массиве. У нас добавляется переменная char question
if question = '1' = трехмерный, если 2, то одномерный.

Вот мой шаблон -

```
template<typename T2>
T2 maxShablon2(T2 ***arr, const int n) {
    int max = arr[0][0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                if (arr[i][j][k] > max) {
                    max = arr[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << " Our max: " << max;
}
```

Comment: у вас возвращается Т2, а return - нету. Может лучше max возвращать?

Comment: может [это поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22423935/9210255)

Comment: [трехзвездочный программист](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) А вообще тут надо не вложенный цикл делать, а вызвать этот же шаблон рекурсивно, когда элементами текущего одномерного массива являются другие массивы.

Comment: А **как** у вас в виде `***` передается одномерный массив?... Да и трехмерный массив - он именно трехмерный **массив**, т.е. объявлен как `int a[3][4][5]`, например, или нет? У вас очень неточная постановка задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Если таки работать надо с **массивами**, то как вариант:

```
template<typename Arr>
auto maxValue(const Arr& a) -> typename remove_all_extents<Arr>::type
{
    static_assert(rank<Arr>::value,"[] type only :)");
    using T = typename remove_all_extents<Arr>::type;
    T res = numeric_limits<T>::min();
    if constexpr(rank<Arr>::value == 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < extent<Arr>::value; ++i)
            if (res < a[i]) res = a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < extent<Arr>::value; ++i)
        {
            T val = maxValue(a[i]);
            if (res < val) res = val;
        }
    }
    return res;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a3[3][2][2] = {
        {{1,2},{3,4}},
        {{5,6},{7,8}},
        {{0,2},{2,4}},
    };
    int a1[5] = { 1, 5, 2, 9, 7 };

    cout << maxValue(a3) << endl;
    cout << maxValue(a1) << endl;
}
```

Вот [рабочая программа](https://ideone.com/e6W5Xz). Размерность массива роли не играет.

И никакой `q` вообще не нужен.

Comment: Я упростил ваш ответ, взгляните.

Answer (score 1):

Массивы располагаются в памяти последовательно, поэтому ответ Harry можно переделать так:

```
template<typename Arr>
auto maxValue(const Arr& a) -> typename
remove_all_extents<Arr>::type {
    using T = typename remove_all_extents<Arr>::type;
    const T* v = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&a[0]);
    T res = numeric_limits<T>::min();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(T); ++i)
        if (v[i] > res) res = v[i];

    return res;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

T2 ***arr это плохой массив. Это вообще неизвестно что, толи 1 значение, толи указатель на массив указателей на элементы....

В C++ должно быть примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

template<typename Cont, typename T>
optional<T> maxShablon2(Cont const& data)
{
    if constexpr (is_same<T, typename Cont::value_type >())
    {
        if (auto it = std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end()); it != data.end())
            return *it;
        return {};
    }
    else
    {
        auto acc_func = [](optional<T> const& a, typename Cont::value_type const& b)->optional<T>
        {
            auto b_res = maxShablon2<typename Cont::value_type, T>(b);
            if (!b_res) return a;
            if (!a) return b_res;
            if (*a > b_res)return a;
            return b_res;
        };

        return std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), optional<T>{}, acc_func);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> v;

    mt19937_64 rg((uint64_t)time(nullptr));

    v.resize(3);
    for (auto& v_x : v)
    {
        v_x.resize(3);
        for (auto& v_xy : v_x)
        {
            v_xy.resize(3);
            for (auto& e : v_xy)
                e = uniform_int_distribution(1, 1000)(rg);
        }
    }

    cout << maxShablon2<decltype(v), int>(v).value_or(-123456);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: T2 ***arr - указатель на указатель на указатель типа Т2.

Comment: Так нельзя решать, без авто и использовать нужно переменную чар.

Идей  у меня просто 0

Comment: @ИванГречка задача решена, компилится и запускается. Если вы навыдумывали себе дополнительных условий, и не сообщили их, то это только ваши проблемы.

Comment: @ИванГречка, а в чем проблема авто?